# How to stop my array parsing all the content in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have two global arrays, but when called outside of the script - it parses all strings instead of 0 to the first call, 1 to the second call, 2 to the third call etc.

The jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var type = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.fancybox({
        'title': title,
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'href' : url,
        'type' : type,
          closeBtn    : true,
    maxWidth  : 467,
    maxHeight  : 609,
    fitToView  : false,
    padding   : '5',
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect  : 'none'
    });
  $('.fancybox').attr('title', altTitle);
});

  window.slideTitles = [   "Title 0",
                        "Title 1",
                        "Title 2"
                     ]; 

  window.altTitle =  [    "This is ALT tag 0",
                       "This is ALT tag 1",
                       "This is ALT tag 2"
                     ]; 
});
```

The HTML:

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="800" height="480" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="59,132,227,367" href="test1.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', window.slideTitles, window.altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="304,108,483,382" href="test2.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', window.slideTitles, window.altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="514,46,747,441" href="test3.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', window.slideTitles, window.altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
</map>
```

How can I make it assign them in sequence please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$('.fancybox').attr('title', altTitle[$(this).index()]);
```

should be

```
$(this).attr('title', altTitle[$(this).index()]);
```

or

```
this.title = altTitle[$(this).index()];
```

Though, I don't exactly understand your question.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've updated $('.fancybox').attr('title', altTitle); to $(this).attr('title', altTitle); but it still gives the output: title="This is ALT tag 0,This is ALT tag 1,This is ALT tag 2" regardless of which link is clicked on. What I want is the third link to pull the third line of the array, so the title tag would say: "This is ALT tag 2".

Comment: PEREFECT!!! Thank you :)  Sorry the question wasn't clear, I didn't really understand what was wrong to make it succinctly clear, as I'm just starting to learn jQuery and arrays!

Answer (score 1):

Really not entirely clear what you are wanting but if it is to create relationship between which area is clicked so you can access proper array index,  use jQuery index() method

http://api.jquery.com/index/

```
$('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
        var index=$(this).index();

        alert( altTitle[index]);

})
```